# php dropzone in an HTML form - submit textarea value to separate database table

Tags: php, upload, dropzone.js

I have a form that uploads multiple files using dropzone - I have that working, and have the values posting to the database.  In the form I have a text area that I want to upload to the same database, but a different table. For reference the images are uploaded to a table called files, which has a column called post_id that will reference the id column in the posts table.  Here's the form:

```
<form action="file_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <textarea class="form-control border-bottom" name="gallery_text" id="gallery_text" placeholder="Add gallery message..."></textarea>
   <div class="dropzone mt-3" id="myDropzone"></div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" name="gallery_submit" id="gallery_submit"> Post Gallery </button>
</form>
```

Here's the current file upload PHP file:

```
// Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

$filename_arr = [];
// Loop through each file
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

    // Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    // Make sure we have a file path
    if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
        // Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "assets/img/posts/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        // Upload the file into the temp dir
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            
            $filename_arr[] = $newFilePath;
            $images_sql = "INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES(?,NOW())";
            $images_stmt = $pdo->prepare($images_sql);
            $images_stmt->execute([$newFilePath]);
        }
    }
}
```

And for reference here's the dropzone script:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: "file_upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 20,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDuplicateFile: "Duplicate Files Cannot Be Uploaded",
    preventDuplicates: true,

    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // For Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("gallery_submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        // Send all the form data along with the files:
        // this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
        //     formData.append("gallery_text", jQuery("#gallery_text").val());
        // });
    }
}
```

I thought I could use `isset` to get the form `textarea` value and upload that to the appropriate table, then use lastInsertId to upload the images as well as reference the post.  Right now I can't seem to get the `textarea` value to upload to the database at all.  Since I'm relatively new at this I'm struggling to understand where I'm going wrong.  I get the feeling I'm missing something. Here's one of the ways I've tried.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $gallery_text = $_POST['gallery_text'];
    $userLoggedIn = $user['username'];

    $text_sql = "INSERT INTO posts(body, added_by, user_to, date_added, user_closed, deleted, likes, image) VALUES(?,?,'',NOW(),'no','no',0,'')";
    $text_stmt = $pdo->prepare($text_sql);
    $text_stmt->execute([$gallery_text, $userLoggedIn]);
}
```

I would be grateful for some guidance on how to get this working.

**EDIT:**

I separated out the form to just submit "gallery_text" and it worked.  When I add dropzone and the image upload process back in it fails silently.  Still searching.  Here's the form that worked:

```
    if (isset($_POST['gallery_submit'])) {
    $gallery_text = $_POST['gallery_text'];
    $userLoggedIn = "steve_shead";
    $date_added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $text_sql = "INSERT INTO posts(body, added_by, user_to, date_added, user_closed, deleted, likes, image) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $text_stmt = $con->prepare($text_sql);
    $text_stmt->execute([$gallery_text, $userLoggedIn,"", $date_added, "no", "no", 0, ""]);

    echo "<h1 class='display-1 mt-5 text-center'>Success!</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the documentation I have it working now.  The form remains the same.  Here's the form handler, file_upload.php:

```
    <?php

require 'inc/header.php';

    $gallery_text = $_POST['gallery_text'];
    $userLoggedIn = $user['username'];
    $date_added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $text_sql = "INSERT INTO posts(body, added_by, user_to, date_added, user_closed, deleted, likes, image) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $text_stmt = $pdo->prepare($text_sql);
    $text_stmt->execute([$gallery_text, $userLoggedIn, "", $date_added, "no", "no", 0, ""]);
    $post_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // Count # of uploaded files in array
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    $filename_arr = [];
    // Loop through each file
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

        // Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        // Make sure we have a file path
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            // Setup our new file path
            $newFilePath = "assets/img/posts/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

            // Upload the file into the temp dir
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                $filename_arr[] = $newFilePath;

                $images_sql = "INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded_on, post_id) VALUES(?,?,?)";
                $images_stmt = $pdo->prepare($images_sql);
                $images_stmt->execute([$newFilePath, $date_added, $post_id]);
            }
        }
}

?>

<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

The notable difference is the $_POST function is handled by the Dropzone jquery - therefore - you don't need the `if(isset($_POST['gallery_text']` function in file_upload.php.  Here's that jquery again - note the last two lines - they tell Dropzone to include the data `name="gallery_text" id="gallery_text"` in the $_POST to file_upload.php.

```
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: "file_upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 20,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDuplicateFile: "Duplicate Files Cannot Be Uploaded",
    preventDuplicates: true,

    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // For Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("gallery_submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        // Send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("gallery_text", jQuery("#gallery_text").val());
        });
    }
}
```

Note also the PDO function `lastInsertId()` - I assigned the variable `$post_id = $pdo->lastInsertId` - that way the text is linked to the images uploaded. When creating the images database table I added an INT row called post_id - by using lastInserId it associated the images with a post (hope that makes sense?)

If anyone is having a similar problem I'd be happy to expand on the solution if you think it would help.